# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false in a non-auth methods after successful login OIDC with Cookie samesite none

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-identity, owin, openid-connect

I'm using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect middleware to implement OIDC login. Because I  have to allow user login via iFrame in popup, then I create the SamesiteCookieManager to set all cookies none for property Samesite

```
 public class SameSiteCookieManager : ICookieManager
        {
            private readonly ICookieManager _innerManager;

            public SameSiteCookieManager() : this(new CookieManager())
            {
            }

            public SameSiteCookieManager(ICookieManager innerManager)
            {
                _innerManager = innerManager;
            }

            public void AppendResponseCookie(IOwinContext context, string key, string value,
                CookieOptions options)
            {
                CheckSameSite(context, options);
                _innerManager.AppendResponseCookie(context, key, value, options);
            }

            public void DeleteCookie(IOwinContext context, string key, CookieOptions options)
            {
                CheckSameSite(context, options);
                _innerManager.DeleteCookie(context, key, options);
            }

            public string GetRequestCookie(IOwinContext context, string key)
            {
                return _innerManager.GetRequestCookie(context, key);
            }

            private void CheckSameSite(IOwinContext context, CookieOptions options)
            {
                options.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                //if (options.SameSite == SameSiteMode.None && DisallowsSameSiteNone(context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString()))
                //{
                //    options.SameSite = null;
                //}
            }
```

And here is Startup :

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/login/"),
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), // default is 14 days!
                SlidingExpiration = true,
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                },
            });

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                CookieName = ".AspNet."+DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager())
            });
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationType = Constants.AuthenticationTypes.OIDC,
                ClientId = _configurationProvider.OIDCClientId,
                ClientSecret = _configurationProvider.OIDCClientSecret,
                Authority = $"{_configurationProvider.OIDCBaseUrl.TrimEnd('/')}/authorize",
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
                Scope = $"{OpenIdConnectScope.OpenId} {OpenIdConnectScope.Email} {OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile}",
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false // This is a simplification
                },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    //RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                    SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityTokenValidated,
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                },
                RedirectUri = _configurationProvider.OIDCRedirectUri,
                UsePkce = false,
                RedeemCode = true,
            });
```

And in callback, I did to process signin:

```
_loginInfo = await _authenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
_userWithLogin = await _userManager.FindAsync(_loginInfo.Login);
  // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
 var result = await _applicationSignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(_loginInfo, false);
 await _applicationSignInManager.SignInAsync(_userWithLogin, false, false);
```

That code run fine without any proplem, but user still not login ̣(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false)

So what's wrong here?

Comment: Are you able to redirect to an authorized controller from your login method?

Comment: Now, I cannot access to an authorized controller.

Comment: Are you using identity server?

Comment: No, I’m not using Identity server

Comment: You're using some provider because oidc is pointing to an authorize endpoint in your authority setting. Ping that endpoint with postman along with your credentials and see if it authorizes you.